# Lombok annotations do not work in netbeans with maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, lombok

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Not generating the getter or setter when using maven and can not find the option to turn it on when I use netbeans maven project.

In maven projects that are not only active when this happens the option that lombok recommended (http://projectlombok.org/setup/netbeans.html) maven project but can not find it and neither generates.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you still experience this issue? What errors Maven shows?

Comment: Maven does not fail, the problem is that netbeans does not see me nor the get set and then when I try to use one of those methods I get an error that the method does not exist.

Comment: not, in the end we decided not to use maven.

Comment: Please note, that Lombok can fail to generate bytecode for other reasons, not necessarily because of NetBeans. For example, [it does not work with AspectJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903686/lombok-does-not-work-with-aspectj).

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me with Netbeans 8

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/lombok_maven_and_netbeans

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Then you should also make a `mvn clean package` in the CLI, before it actually works.

Comment: I had a similar issue using Lombok 1.16.6 being built within Netbeans 8.1RC.  It appeared Lombok was not generating a constructor within a class with two final String variables (with both variables as parameters to the constructor).  Simply downgrading to 1.14.4 fixed it.  Just to be sure, I switched back to 1.16.6 and it broke again.

Answer (score 0):

### Source :

[Dzone](http://netbeans.dzone.com/tips/using-lombok-netbeans-platform)

### Solution :

As per the Lombok documentation, usually you only need to put this in your pom:

```
<repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
        <id>projectlombok.org</id>
        <name>Lombok Repository</name>
        <url>http://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It works, but the Maven NBM plugin will embed the lombok jar into the generated .nbm. To avoid that, you just need to add the scope element as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't fix it. This solution on DZone regards the *packaging* into a NB module, rather than internal NB annotation processors.

Comment: @nevvermind I use also lombok with maven 3 and netbeans 7.3 => no problem here.